# Pillow image colors looking weird

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

Pillow is pasting the profile picture on the base image, but the colors are looking weird. Here's the code:

```py
from discord import file
from discord.client import Client
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        if user == None:
            user = ctx.author

        msg = await ctx.send('Generating profile, please wait!')
        img = Image.open('card.png')
        asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
        data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
        pfp = Image.open(data).convert('RGB') 
        pfp = pfp.resize((100,100))  
        img.paste(pfp, (75,71))
        img.save('profile.png')

        file = discord.File('profile.png', filename='profile.png')
        await msg.delete()
        await ctx.send(file=file)
```

[image: This] This is the base image.
[image: This] This is the image after running the command.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It looks like the original image has a limited palette, and the new one isn't adding colors to the palette of the original. As for how to fix it I wouldn't know, but it seems like a palette issue at least. Maybe you have to convert it after importing it?

Comment: @RandomDavis thank you. This actually was the problem. I forgot to embed the Color Profile in Photoshop.